# Difference in results between run and debug in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

When I use `run` (Run > Run) for a package (exactly [mriqc](https://pypi.org/project/mriqc/)) in pycharm, everything seems to work fine.

When I use `debug` (Run > Debug) for the same repository in pycharm, the execution gets stuck. Exactly in multiprocessing.managers.Server.serve_forever(), it gets stuck in the following `while` statement:

```
while not self.stop_event.is_set() :
    self.stop_event.wait(1)
```

I don't know if the issue is a bug in pycharm or if I have to change something in the configuration (Run > Edit Configuration). However, if it's a configuration problem, it's curious that it works in `Run` and that it stays stuck in `debug` mode... ? ???

Comment: Are you sure someone is setting the `stop_event`?  Is one of the processes waiting in the debugger?

Comment: I'm sure it's blocked in the while statement, because I followed the execution step by step. If I use `step into` it doesn't get out of the while!

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions.  You're using multiprocessing, so there is more than one process to consider.

Comment: Oh I see! You are right. I was just running several instances (in pycharm) and directly on the host. I think you found the solution. Thanks a lot.